# 思いついた plural or singular?

Tags: translation, meaning

It's not the full sentence but i heard this : 方法を思いついた 
And i was wondering if it means that the person came up with a method alone or it could be a few people who have

Answer (score 2):

As is the case with many other Japanese sentences, without enough context, you can never tell the implied subject of this sentence. It typically means someone came up with a solution alone, but depending on the context, it can safely mean a group of people discussed and came up with a solution together.